# How to use ssh tunnelling in intellij spring boot application

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea, ssh-tunnel

I want to integrate third party APIs into my spring boot application. But the third party APIs work only in some environments where the IPs are enabled from third party.

I am able to run those APIs using postman using the below mentioned way:
https://medium.com/teamarimac/access-a-server-through-ssh-tunnel-and-send-api-requests-through-postman-in-windows-10-b7307974c1a0

Need to know how run this in my local using ssh tunnelling from intellij to integrate and test.

Tried various ways but could not find any solution.

Comment: Not sure what your scenario is, call a 3rd-party API locally by using an ssh tunnel? Maybe connect to SSH server from a Java client like SSHJ (https://github.com/hierynomus/sshj) could help.

Answer (score 0):

If your app is in localhost and you need to serve it publicly. you can use `ngrok` for tunneling.

It is a very  simple setup and should  work like a charm for you.

To configure it you can visit https://ngrok.com/docs/getting-started/

Comment: Ngrok doesn’t work as we need to forward request from localhost to other env and in the other env I don’t have any app running

Comment: @reddyshekar, `we need to forward request from localhost to other env`, how does it not wrok?

Comment: could you elaborate how to use ngrok url as ssh proxy in intellij ?

Comment: You must  be deploying your application in some sort of server, right? say `localhost:8080`, I am saying you can use ngrok to tunnel this particular server and port